# What's the project name of Eclipse 4.9?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-photon

I don't mean the name of my own projects, but e.g. "Photon" from Eclipse 4.8 or "Neon" from Eclipse 4.6.

Comment: Probably something starting with a Q, but my guess would be that it does not have a name yet, at least not officially. Why do you need to know anyway?

Comment: I am the creator of the latest portable Eclipse versions on SourceForge and have always added the project name to my releases so far.

Comment: FAQ site explains a lot: https://wiki.eclipse.org/SimRel/Simultaneous_Release_Cycle_FAQ

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The naming system has changed and in future the main 'simultaneous releases' will be every three months and known by the year and month. So the next release is '[SimRel 2018-09](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Category:SimRel-2018-09)' (or just 2018-09) followed by 'SimRel 2018-12'.

The core Eclipse Project SDK will still be numbered as 4.9 ....

Comment: So will there never be unique names for the releases again?

Comment: Not in the current plan

Comment: `SimRel 2018-09`, with only one `-` in the date: https://wiki.eclipse.org/SimRel/Simultaneous_Release_Cycle_FAQ#What_is_the_naming_pattern_for_the_releases_.3F and the SDK will have the version number 4.9.0 instead of 4.8.1.

Comment: Now I'm depressed

Comment: Is that because there is no well-known gas, star, or planet that starts with the letter Q? (side note: in one year, Android will face the same challenge!)

Comment: Maybe they just couldnt pronounce Quaoar: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_named_minor_planets:_Q

Comment: Could they have not just used Quasar?

Comment: @code11 how about something with Quantum? Or is that too mainstream? ^^

Comment: Or "Quark" since it is also a subatomic particle?